# How many elements need to be in a hash table to force an 11-way collision?

Tags: math, hash

I’m working on this problem:

> You have a hash table of size 100. What is the minimum number of elements needs to be hashed to the hash table such that at least 11 of the elements are guarantee to have  the same hash value, irrespective of the hash function?

According to me, it should be 111, since 100 unique possible hash values are present; if 11 of them are guaranteed to have the same hash, then it should be 100 + 11 = 111.

However, the given answer is 1001.

Is my answer correct? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine your hash table has the world’s silliest hash function of just taking the input and modding it by 100.

Now, insert the elements 1, 2, 3, ..., 111 into the table. How many elements will be in each of the 100 slots?

To see where 1001 comes from, think about this problem in a different way. How many elements can you cram into a hash table such that every slot has fewer than 11 elements? Adding one more element into that will force some slot to have 11 elements.